# JUnit/Mockito - How to capture changes in an argument's field?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have an ObservableBoolean which is a pretty simple data container wrapping a primitive boolean. I want to use JUnit/Mockito to verify that the primitive boolean's value changes to true followed by false. I am setting up a mock OnPropertyChangedCallback like so:

```
Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback loadingCallback = mock(Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback.class);
viewModel.loading.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(loadingCallback);
```

I am then running the code under test which does:

```
loading.set(true);
loading.set(false);
```

Each of these calls fires the onPropertyChanged method on the loadingCallback, passing the *same* ObservableBoolean instance as an argument.

I've tried using an ArgumentCaptor and a custom ArgumentMatcher. Both methods successfully show that the onPropertyChange method has been called twice, however, neither of them maintain a history of what happened to the primitive boolean within the ObservableBoolean. Instead, I can only see the most recent value set on it, which is false.

How can I maintain a history of what happened to the primitive boolean within the ObservableBoolean? Again, I simply need to verify that it was set to true followed by false.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same situation now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a *stub* which implements `Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback` and records the invocations and then provides a public accessor to these recorded invocations. Your test would then use the public accessor to these recorded invocations when asserting.

For example:

```
    OnPropertyChangedCallbackStub loadingCallback = new OnPropertyChangedCallbackStub();
    viewModel.loading.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(loadingCallback);

    // invoke the code-under-test which, internally, invokes ...
    // loading.set(true);
    // loading.set(false);

    assertTrue(2, loadingCallback.recordedInvocations().size());
    assertTrue(loadingCallback.recordedInvocations().contains(true));
    assertTrue(loadingCallback.recordedInvocations().contains(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the implementation of the class @glytching suggested in his answer:

```
val callback = BooleanObservableCallback()
        viewModel.isLoading.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback)

viewModel.onLoginButtonClicked()

assertThat(callback.recordedInvocations, hasSize(2))
        assertThat(callback.recordedInvocations[0], `is`(true))
        assertThat(callback.recordedInvocations[1], `is`(false))


class BooleanObservableCallback : Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {

    private val _recordedInvocations = mutableListOf<Boolean>()

    val recordedInvocations: List<Boolean>
        get() = _recordedInvocations.toList()

    override fun onPropertyChanged(sender: Observable?, propertyId: Int) {
        if (sender is ObservableBoolean) {
            _recordedInvocations.add(sender.get())
        }
    }
}
```